# Google VRView video controls

Tags: html, video, html5-video, google-vr, 360-degrees

I have implemented [Google VRView](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview-web) and have 360 video playback in an app I am working on. Playback is great, but I am missing video controls (which isn't advertised, so they of course could simply not be an option). Are video controls (basics like skipping ahead, play, pause, etc) an option with VRView? If not, are there any solutions or do I need to simply find a different 360 player?

Comment: hi daniel did u find any solution for this ?? am also stuck in this